In Angular 17, if I try to compare a variable with 'undefined', while compiling it automatically replaces 'undefined' with 'null'
I have used Bootstrap DatePicker which on emptying return undefined event. When in my TS file: I try to compare if event is undefined, it never goes in that if block. Because in my browser when I check the compiled code, it has replaced undefined with null.
HTML File:
<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-xl-3">
                <label for="serviceDueDate">{{
                  commonService.labelConstants.SERVICE_DUE_DATE
                  }}</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend" (click)="serviceDueDate.toggle()"
                    [attr.aria-expanded]="serviceDueDate.isOpen">
                    <div class="input-group-text outline">
                      <i class="fa fa-calendar" id="from-calendar-btn"></i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <input id="serviceDueDate" appAutocompleteOff type="text" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
                    class="form-control form-control-sm" maxlength="10" [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" bsDatepicker
                    (bsValueChange)="serviceDueDateFocusOut($event)"
                    [bsConfig]="bsConfig" formControlName="serviceDueDate" #serviceDueDate="bsDatepicker" />
                </div>
</div>

TS File:
serviceDueDateFocusOut(event) {
    if(event == undefined) {
      // Do something
    } else if(event == null) {
      // Do Another Thing
    }
}

After Compilation JS File (Can be viewed in Browser, opening Inspect Element):
serviceDueDateFocusOut(event) {
    if(event == null) {
      // Do something
    } else if(event == null) {
      // Do Another Thing
    }
}

Here if I debug this, event comes out to be undefined, But it couldn't go in either if blocks.

Does undefined also get replaced if you use strict equality? if (event === undefined)

The problem here is how Angular and TypeScript handle the comparison between undefined and null. When TS compiles to JS, it can optimize certain comparisons in ways we do not expect/necessarily want.
To work around this, the easiest way is to simply be more robust with your checks.
For example:
serviceDueDateFocusOut(event: any) {
    if (typeof event === 'undefined') {
      // Do something
    } else if (event === null) {
      // Do Another Thing
    } else {
      // Do Another Thing 2
    }
}

Here is a stackblitz I set up that shows this in action.
Change the variable buttonValue to null or undefined, then run the stackblitz and click the button. It will output the correct value.
You'll notice that if you use my more verbose check, it'll display the correct value. If you use your check, the return will be null no matter what variable you use.
Hope this helps!

Thanks for your response. It even gives void0 sometimes. Can you explain that? (How is it different from null & undefined)
